# How do I use Scala regular expressions to parse a line of text?

Tags: regex, scala

I am using Scala to process a data-rich line of text, a sample of which is:

```
0101 Test        A123456-7 N   Ag Ri              R 123 Im K8 V
```

In order to parse this, I've ported over the regex I use in other languages.  But, I'm doing something wrong.  My faulty object is:

```
object UwpParser extends App
{
   val Pattern = "^(\\d\\d\\d\\d) (\\S.+) ([ABCDEX]\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d) (..)\\s*(\\w.{17}) (.) (\\d\\d\\d) (\\w\\w) (.*)$".r;

   var data = scala.io.Source.fromFile( "test.txt" ).getLines.mkString;

   for (p <- Pattern findAllIn data) p match
   {
      case Pattern(c) => println( c )
      case _ => None
   }
}
```

The purpose of the for block is just to see if I've captured my data.  Obviously I haven't.  I'm sure I'm doing a number of things wrong.  I've trawled stackoverflow, but the questions seem different from this one, or else there's something I'm just not getting.

**UPDATE**.  Thanks to the guy who posted the scaladoc reference!  My corrected code is:

```
object UwpParser extends App
{
   val Pattern = """^(\d\d\d\d) (\S.+) ([ABCDEX]\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d) (..)\s*(\w.{17}) (.) (\d\d\d) (\w\w) (.*)$""".r;

   var data = scala.io.Source.fromFile( "test.txt" ).getLines.mkString;  

   data match {
      case Pattern(hex, name, uwp, bases, codes, zone, pbg, alleg, stellar) => println( s"$name ($hex) $uwp" );
   }
}
```

Comment: replace  `(\\S.+)` with `(\\S+)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the scaladoc to see how Scala's regexps differ from those of other languages.  Based on my assumptions, though, your suggestion might not work in my case, since the second capture group could have spaces in it.

Comment: I hope your not using such hideous regex for any production code!! Suggest learning Scala `String` manipulation libraries so that you can write READABLE, MAINTAINABLE, and EFFICIENT code ( in short; regex is for noobs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is clarified scaladoc in the latest nightly:

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.x/#scala.util.matching.Regex

with plenty of examples of capturing groups in pattern matches.

I hope this version of the doc is an easier read.

Also, don't you intend to match your regex against each line of `data`?

```
val p = """your regex""".r
for (line <- text.getLines) {
  line match {
    case p(field1, field2, field3, _*) => // do something with first 3 capturing groups
  }
}
```

Rather than glue and unglue the input.

Just for fun and completeness:

```
scala> val text = "Now is the time\nfor all good men\nto come home for dinner."
text: String =
Now is the time
for all good men
to come home for dinner.

scala> val r = """(?m)^(\S+)\s*(.*)$""".r
r: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = (?m)^(\S+)\s*(.*)$

scala> r findAllMatchIn text map (_ group 1) toList
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res0: List[String] = List(Now, for, to)

scala> r findAllMatchIn text map { case r(first, rest) => s"$first! ($rest)" } toList
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res1: List[String] = List(Now! (is the time), for! (all good men), to! (come home for dinner.))
```

Actually, that was to remind myself what the inline flags are. That's `m` for multiline.

Comment: Thank you!  That's exactly what I need.  I'll append my corrected code to the original post.